# Produce ISEA "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" GEOTIFF/raster with gdalwarp

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

Is an icosahedral projection impossible to produce with PROJ/GDAL ?

[image: desired output from gdalwarp]

Produce ISEA "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" GEOTIFF/raster with gdalwarp.
I am trying to use gdal tools to convert Plate-Carree to ISEA and back.

The input GeoTIFF is "NE1_50M_SR_W.tif"
directly from  "The Natural Earth quick start kit" at https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

I can find no input format or argument permutation that satisfies this error message.

```
gdalwarp  -te -180 -90 +180 +90     -t_srs "+proj=isea +elipse=sphere" NE1_50M_SR_W.tif out-isea.tif
ERROR 1: Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.



gdalinfo NE1_50M_SR_W.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: NE1_50M_SR_W.tif
Size is 10800, 5400
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-179.999999999999972,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.033333333333330,-0.033333333333330)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2014:10:18 09:32:38
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (Macintosh)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=342.85699
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=342.85699
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (  -0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=10800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=10800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=10800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
molly@morfydd:~/Documents/earthgeo/gdal/scripttest$
```

Comment: I believe that transforamation into ISEA is not possible with gdalwarp. But in any case you should use the parameters in a correct way. ISEA is using meters as units (projected coordinates) https://proj.org/en/9.3/operations/projections/isea.html. If you give `-te` in EPSG:4326 coordinates, add also `-te_srs epsg:4326` as documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te_srs.